# Populate DOM after view init with Angular

Tags: angular, calendar

I'm trying to build a calendar component in Angular. This is my HTML structure so far:

```
<tr>
    <td *ngFor="let cell of cells" id="{{cell}}">{{cell}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td *ngFor="let cell of cells" id="{{+cell+7}}">{{+cell+7}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td *ngFor="let cell of cells" id="{{+cell  +14}}">{{+cell  +14}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td *ngFor="let cell of cells" id="{{+cell  + 21}}">{{+cell  + 21}}</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
    <td *ngFor="let cell of cells" id="{{+cell  + 28}}">{{+cell  + 28}}</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
    <td *ngFor="let cell of cells" id="{{+cell  + 35}}">{{+cell  + 35}}</td> 
</tr>
```

It is basicly a table with 42 cells and 7 cells each row and an ID with the number of the cell. My question now is: is there a way to populate those cells with the correct days?

For example: I have the number of the first weekday of a month (in Feb it is 5 for Saturday). I want to start iterating from the element with the id 5, starting with 1, and set it's inner HTML to the value of the iterator.

Anyone an idea how to accomplish this or a hint so I can maybe figure out myself?

Kind regards
Fonzane